# App runs out of memory due to a huge UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, core-animation, didreceivememorywarning

I have to show a huge text file in my app.
An `UITextView` do not fit my requirements because it forces line wrapping so I had to use an `UILabel`. Since very big labels do not get rendered, I'm using several `UILabels` inside an `UIScrollView` to make it work.

Everything works on the simulator but the required memory for the `UILabels` is about 300MB. When I run it on an iPad 2, it gets out of memory and the application crash.

The problem is that I'm not getting any memory warning. I would like to dismiss the view controller in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` but it is not been called, the app crashes without any warning.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there really 300MB of text in those labels?

Comment: I thought the same... Of course not, there is attributed text. But I think the problem is not the text but the rendered image of the `UILabel`. I have an empty view over the labels and I can create all of them. The app crashes when this view is hidden and the labels are shown.

Comment: it's bad practice to load everything in memory even when not displayed on the screen. make sure you load as needed and remove objects from memory that aren't needed.

Comment: I'm using ARC. How can I do it inside a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Sounds like a tableview would be better, as that solves the issue of just displaying what can be seen?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I would need to put it inside a scroll view to provide horizontal scroll... The problem is that I would like to avoid rewriting the full thing using the memory warning. However, I read that it doesn't work when memory is allocated very quickly, that is exactly my problem.

Comment: Your problem is that you're creating a 300MB `UILabel`. Find a better solution, such as the `UITableView` route recommended by @trojanfoe.

Comment: Why not break up the text into pages and use a UIPageViewController? What possible requirement has to show 300MB of text in one page on a mobile device?

Comment: Finally I created an `UITableView` with one row for each line. Then, in each row I used an `UIScrollView` with a label inside. Making the rows 17 pixels height make it look nice. And, since it is a table view, cells are removed from memory when not displayed so there is no crash.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using a `UITableView` to solve your problem.

**HSViewController.h**

```
@interface HSViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

**HSViewController.m**

```
#import "HSViewController.h"

//#define USE_LABEL

static NSString *const kCellIdentifier = @"kCellIdentifier";

@interface HSViewController ()

@property (atomic, strong) NSArray *linesOfText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIFont *font;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSLineBreakMode lineBreakMode;

- (CGSize)sizeForString:(NSString *)text;

@end

@implementation HSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *draculaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Dracula" withExtension:@"txt"]];
        NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:draculaData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
#ifndef USE_LABEL
        self.linesOfText = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
#endif
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
#ifdef USE_LABEL
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                       self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
            label.font = self.font;
            label.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            label.text = text;
            [self.view addSubview:label];
#else
            NSLog(@"Starting reloading %lu rows", (unsigned long)[self.linesOfText count]);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"Reload finished");
#endif
        });
    });
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#ifdef USE_LABEL
    return 0;
#else
    return [self.linesOfText count];
#endif
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = self.font;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
        cell.textLabel.text = self.linesOfText[indexPath.row];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return cell;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *text = self.linesOfText[indexPath.row];
        // Don't let the line height be 0
        if ([text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0)
        {
            text = @"A";
        }
        return ceil([self sizeForString:text].height);
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (CGSize)sizeForString:(NSString *)text
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])
        {
            NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
            style.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
            return [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : self.font,
                                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : [style copy]}
                                      context:[NSStringDrawingContext new]].size;
        }
        else
        {
            return [text sizeWithFont:self.font
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                        lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

You'll find that there's actually not a big difference in memory usage. The `UITableView` version only saves approx. 10% on memory.

However, this is a starting point for dynamically loading up table view cells. So when the user scrolls down (to let's say 90% of the screen) the next X cells can be loaded by changing the return value of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Good luck.